# htaccess 301 redirect with ? (question mark) in URL not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

This is probably a simple question, but I can not find why the 301 with an ? in the URL is not working. I have done a 301 redirect in the .htacces file but it´s not working. Other 301-redirects are working except for the one with a question mark in the URL.

I want `http://www.example.com/?forum=2115543` redirected to `http://www.example.com` but the simple standard 301-redirect doesn´t work.

Example in .htaccess: `Redirect 301 /?forum=2115543 /`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not match a query string with `Redirect (mod_alias)`. You need to use `mod_rewrite`.

You can give this a try.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^forum=(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /? [R=301,L]
```